# Elegant way to re sub an uuid1()?

Tags: python, regex

What would be the most elegant way in Python to substitute a regular expression search with a uuid?

```
re.sub(r'guid="([0-9a-f-]{36})"', uuid1(), contents)
```

The above statement fails because of this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'UUID' has no len()
```

Would this be an appropriate scenario to explore the usage of lambda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`uuid.uuid1()` returns a `uuid.UUID` object. The second argument of `re.sub` expects a callable or a string. In this case, convert `uuid1()` to a string: `str(uuid1())`:

```
re.sub(r'guid="([0-9a-f-]{36})"', str(uuid1()), contents)
```

Comment: class GUIDGenerator:
    def __call__(self, s):
        return str(uuid1())

Comment: Adding the callable method to a new class returns a new uuid for each match.